# How to delete rows without using break in matlab

Tags: matlab, rows

So this is my code:

```
in=-8:8;
%calculate z
[h,k,l]=meshgrid(in);
z = (h.^2 + k.^2 + l.^2);

%sort absolute values ascending, which allows to use unique
ac=sort(abs([h(:) k(:) l(:)]),2);
%use unique to identify duplicates
[f,g,p]=unique(ac,'rows');
%count
cnt=histc(p,1:max(p));
% create a matrix with all vectors
disp([h(g),k(g), l(g),z(g),cnt])
```

i just want to delete or terminate rows containing z>59, i can't used break because it only works in for loop or while loop, so what other command may i used? thanks.

Comment: in which matrix you want to delete that rows?

Comment: a matrix that was already sorted, and has column of counts

Comment: so the one you display, like ´output = [h(g),k(g), l(g),z(g),cnt]´?

Comment: yes sir. like what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess you want this:

```
%// your output matrix you want to filter
output = [h(g),k(g), l(g),z(g),cnt];
%// delete rows containing z > 59 (z is the 4th column)
filtered_output = output(output(:,4) <= 59,:)
```